# MessageDialog ignores RequestedTheme in windows phone universal app

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

In my application I set Light theme as requested theme `App.Current.RequestedTheme = ApplicationTheme.Light;` all the application is applying this Light theme no matter what is the current phone theme. But all `MessageDialog` are using Phone theme. e.g phone theme is Dark `MessageDialog` is applying Dark theme.

Is there any way to set `MessageDialog` theme?

Comment: No, I think you can only write a custom dialog using Popup control for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [ContentDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx)  for Windows Phone part of Universal app, for Windows part use Flyout or Popup